# Cannot run program "mvn" although maven on path

Tags: maven, gradle

Before marking this as duplicate please read carefully.
A gradle task (kotlin dsl) I am executing is executing a maven command in a sub directory. The weird thing is I have maven on the PATH variable both on System and User. If I navigate into that directory using the CMD or git bash I can execute any maven command.
So it can't be the issue of it simply not being in the environment variables. I actually had that issue in every project where a mvn command is executed by code.

```kotlin
fun cmd(vararg args: String, directory: File, printToStdout: Boolean = false): Pair<Int, String?> {
    val p = ProcessBuilder()
            .command(*args)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .directory(directory)
            .start()
    val output = p.inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
        val lines = LinkedList<String>()
        it.lines().peek(lines::add).forEach { line ->
                println(line)
        }
        lines.joinToString(separator = "\n")
    }
    val exit = p.waitFor()
    return exit to output
}
```

Calling it like so:

```kotlin
cmd("mvn", "install:install-file", "-q", "-Dfile=${project.projectDir.resolve("work/1.15.2-mojang-mapped.jar").absolutePath}", "-Dpackaging=jar", "-DgroupId=me.minidigger", "-DartifactId=minecraft-server", "-Dversion=\"$minecraftversion-SNAPSHOT\"", directory = project.projectDir)
```

It results in:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "....."): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

Edit: It shouldn't be the code, as others dont have this issue.
I am btw using windows 10

**Update:** so it appears that while "mvn" works when calling it manually, it has to be "mvn.bat" if called from code. Being forced to manually change and check that in the code does not seem like an optimal solution though. Especially because some of the code calling mvn is downloaded in the task and can't be edited manually before

Comment: Does it work with the full path to the mvn command?

Comment: I chekced that. It appears thats not the issue. I figured I need to add a .bat to the end of mvn to make it work.
So mvn.bat does it... I'd still like mvn itself to work too

Comment: Then invoke a command processor to do it.

Comment: The `mvn` script is a shell script for Linux/Unix environments. Under Windows, you need to use the `mvn.bat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check what your `ProcessBuilder.environment` shows as available variables. You may have to define these variables yourself.

Comment: What exaclty should I be looking for?
it contains:
`MAVEN_HOME -> D:\Programme\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3`
or `Path -> ...;D:\Programme\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;...`
looks correct to me

Comment: The variable should be called `M2_HOME`, if i recall correctly, not `MAVEN_HOME`. Could you try renaming it (and possibly restarting after that)?